# How do I remove index/index from controller URL?

Tags: frontend, router

I have :

```
<?php
class Example_Module_IndexController extends Mage_Core_Controller_Front_Action
{
    public function indexAction()
```

which I can call with http://www.example.com/module/index/index or http://www.example.com/module/ where index/index is inferred.

However I want to be able have different params in the URL and a short URL. Therefore I want to send anything that goes to http://www.example.com/module/ to my module and regard anything after 'module' as parameters.

Therefore rather than http://www.example.com/module/index/index/id/5 I want http://www.example.com/module/id/5

How can I achieve that?

Comment: what is your  module name?

Comment: anything - it does not have to be anything other than a frontname.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You could try using a magento rewrite

In your config.xml

```
...
<global>
    <rewrite>
    <fancy_url>
            <from><![CDATA[/module\/(.*)/]]></from>
            <to><![CDATA[module/index/index/id/$1/]]></to>
                <complete>1</complete>
    </fancy_url>
  ...
```

Comment: That actually works! I sound surprised, which I am. Thank you very much!